# How to edit a text field by touching a button within a cell swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, first-responder

I have a textfield in the collectionview controller, and I want to be able to call it by pressing a button which is in a cell. Is there a way to make that textfield firstResponder() from within a cell?

Comment: how many sections are in your collection view?

Comment: I think just the 1

Comment: got a couple of other questions, just to make sure I'm going the right direction. is the text field also in the cell, or is it just a property of your view controller outside the collectionView?

Comment: if the text field is outside the collection view, it's very straightforward. If each cell has it's own text field that needs to be activated when the button is pressed, that's a little more involved but I can write some sample code to help.

Comment: Yeah the textfield is in the main view controller as I said.  It's actually not even in the collection view, just overlapping the whole thing.

Comment: textfield you want to use is you use in all collectionview cell ? or it outside of collectionview ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I got it working but I'm not sure how efficient it is so if anyone knows of a better way to do this please post answers and I will select the best one after a day or 2.  This is what I used:

```
button.addTarget(self.supernode, action: #selector(CollectionViewController.buttonTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

The reason it says "supernode" is because I'm using asyncdisplaykit but superview should do the same thing, unless you have to step up twice instead of once, not sure.  Anyway I used this to run a function called buttonTapped() in the main view controller.

```
func buttonTapped(sender: ASButtonNode) {
        self.txtField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

Again replace node with view if using uikit or storyboard or w/e.  Let me know please if this isn't the "proper" way because performance is important to me.

Comment: You got it right. Typically sender would be a UIButton

Comment: what is use of this ASButtonNode ? why u put it there

Comment: As I said I'm using AsyncDisplayKit and it uses nodes instead of views so just replace the word "node" with "view" if using UIKit / Storyboard.  I think I mentioned that in the answer twice lol..